# Selenium: find part of identifier

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The next command does not work

```
wd.findElement(By.id("post_message_*"));
```

The goal is to find id's with *post_message_3456346*, *post_message_01548* and so on. How to fix it?

Actulay there is only one id on page which starts with "post_message_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to locate required element by `XPath` as below:

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'post_message_')]"));
```

or by `CSS` selector

```
wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[id^='post_message_']"));
```

Comment: Fist resuts with error - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //*[starts-with(@id, 'post_message_'] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

Comment: Yep, forgot closing parenthesis. Updated

Answer (score 0):

Try using a css Selector

```
wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id^='post_message_']"));
```